# How do you deploy a Node.js application to Google App Engine without any Docker files?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, docker

I am deploying a new Node.js application to Google App Engine. I use Docker for local development so I have the following files in my root folder:

- Dockerfile
- .dockerignore
- docker-compose.yml
- docker-compose.debug.yml

When I run `gcloud app deploy`, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) There is a Dockerfile in the current directory, and the runtime field in /Users/Nag/Code/project/web-service/app.yaml is currently set to [runtime: nodejs]. To use your Dockerfile to build a custom runtime, set the runtime field to [runtime: custom]. To continue using the [nodejs] runtime, please remove the Dockerfile from this directory.
```

As per the Google App Engine [app.yaml settings](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#general), I can include a `skip_files` key to ignore certain files. I included `skip_files` key in my app.yaml like this but it still throws the same error:

```
# [START app_yaml]
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
skip_files:
    - /docker/i
automatic_scaling:
    min_num_instances: 1
    max_num_instances: 2
env_variables:
    NODE_ENV: development
# [END app_yaml]
```

I would like to continue using the nodejs runtime when the application is running on App Engine and use Docker only on my local machine. I can't Git ignore the Docker files because other developers on the team need access to it in the repository. Can someone please help me understand why App Engine still recognizes my Docker files even though I am skipping them? Thanks.

Comment: I believe your regex may be wrong for skip_files.  To verify, you can add "Dockerfile" directly into skip_files.

Comment: If `Dockerfile` isn't actually in your app dir try running `gcloud app deploy` from inside your app dir or, better yet, specify the config file as well: `gcloud app deploy <path_to/>app.yaml`.

Comment: @DanCornilescu Dockerfile is in my root directory. I can't really move this to another location without causing a bunch of issues related to Docker volumes etc.

Comment: @JeffDeskins That didn't really work either.

Comment: @Nag This means you're running `gcloud app deploy` from your root directory. Try my earlier suggestions (without moving the Dockerfile).

Comment: @Nag Did you manage to solve this? I am facing similar issue

Comment: @Rushipatel yes, I did manage to figure it out. The trick is to move your Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml and any other Docker-related files away from your project root and into its own folder. For example, you can create a folder called ./docker_dev in your project root and place your Docker files there. This way, App Engine won't read these files.